# Chrome based browsers constantly keep crashing with error 61696

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, brave, brave-browser

I have recently installed Fedora 33, and attempted to run both chromium and the brave browser.
I have maybe one or two tabs open and often I get sad chrome error page on both browsers:

[image]

This happens when I open a new tab, or when I have a tab open for a while and while I'm reading it. It is a fresh install, so theres no add-ons or extensions, its a fairly vanilla system (2 days old).
I have tried to search google and stackoverflow for some help, with no avail. Does anyone know what the chromium error code 61696 means, or where I can get some more help on this error code from.

Clicking the "learn more" link, just takes me to a generic page with very little help, other than things like refresh the page or restart the browser. Which obviously does not help.

I appreciate some people may not think this is programming related, but I feel like this is a bug in the chromium code.

Comment: Better ask this question in the official Chromium dev Google group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev

Comment: The same issue. Nothing in Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still interested, I have upgraded both my kernel and chromium and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Surprisingly very little information out there on this little bug.